# text aligned to the left and another text aligned to the right on the same line with different height

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```html
<div>
  <div style="float:left">
      <h2>header</h2>
  </div>
  <span style="float:right; vertical-align: bottom">
          text2
  </span>
  <div class="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

I am not able to vertically align the `text2` to the bottom of the parent `div`.

How to do it?

Comment: Headers have a margin

Comment: Changed code : https://jsfiddle.net/pze8xgu0/ (Not sure if you are really looking for this) But I believe this will help you progress further

Comment: thank you, reset margin or add margin to the text2 also solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's  rather strange HTML code, but here's a solution that doesn't change the HTML:

(P.S.: You asked that the `span` should align with the bottom of the parent DIV, not wth the `h1`. If you want the latter, you have to give them both the same `margin-bottom` and `padding-bottom`.)

```css
div:first-of-type {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="float:left">
      <h2>header</h2>
  </div>
  <span style="float:right; vertical-align: bottom">
          text2
  </span>
  <div class="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to consider changing the elements you are using since h2 and span dont have the same default user agent style. h2 will appear bolder/ bigger than span and span appear lighter. That is why you see it not to be aligned

try this

```
`<div style="float:left">
    <h2>header</h2>
</div>
<div style="float:right; vertical-align: bottom">
        <h2> text2</h2>
</div>
<div class="clear:both"></div>`
```